# How to add server side validation if email attribute is unique in an ASP .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to implement a server side validation for email, where email field will only take unique value and to implement it I used fluent API for unique email which is like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Manager>()
            .HasIndex(b => b.Email)
            .IsUnique();
}
```

And now whenever I try to enter duplicate email it throws an exception like this:

> SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Managers' with unique index 'IX_Managers_Email'. The duplicate key value is (test@gmail.com). The statement has been terminated.

How can I stop this and instead letting compiler throw this exception, I make it throw a server side validation or is there another way to do it? Please guide.

Plus adding Manager model as well in case if it is needed

```
namespace Office.Models
{
    [Index (nameof(Email), IsUnique=true)]
    public class Manager
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Manager Name")]
        public string ManagerName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(450)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        //[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$", ErrorMessage = "Password type is not valid include Capital, Small, number and Special Char and length should be Min 8")]
        public string Password{ get; set; }

        public string Role { get; set; } = "2";
        public DateTime JoiningDate { get; private set; }

        public Manager()
        {
            JoiningDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried making `Email` unique and expected email to simply not accepting duplicate values and do nothing or throw server side validation, but I got this error

> SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Managers' with unique index 'IX_Managers_Email'. The duplicate key value is (test@gmail.com). The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a unique index to a field of a table in database (apparently it is `Manager` table in your case), the validation error occurs in database level. So it throws an exception and EF Core will pass it through your code(.net-core level), if you don't handle that exception using `try-catch` block, your application will give you the unhandled error. You can use `try-catch` like this:

```
try {
    //the code that inserts a Manager field to database
}
catch (Exception e) {
   // give a handled message to the user which says the email was taken.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Remote attribute to achieve it. Please refer to this simple demo:

Create a action in Home controller:

```
        [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> IsEmailInUse(string email)
        {
            //check if the emailAddress already exists or not in database
            var user = await _dbContext.managers.Where(x => x.Email == email).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (user == null)
            {
                return Json(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json($"Email {email} is already in use");
            }
        }
```

Add remote attribute on this property:

```
[Remote(action: "IsEmailInUse", controller: "Home")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@model Manager
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

Demo:

When you enter duplicate email, The form will show error message and not allow you to submit the form.

[image]

Comment: that will work for creating but think of a scenario where i am trying to update or edit an entity without changing its Email , that will throw an error (Email admin@gmail.com is already in use) because technically that email does exist in database

Comment: You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341952/cannot-insert-duplicate-key-row-in-object-with-unique-index-the-duplicate-key).